# SQL Server Setup with SSRS (creating/using Views, SPs and UDFs)

Tags: performance, installation, reporting-services, cpu-usage

What is the best considered way to save and use Views, SPs and UDFs for SSRS reporting services that will be used by many users and some reports subscribed being sent out?

Do I:

1. Write it to a table overnight via scheduled jobs to do a direct read to the pre-saved query results?
2. Use a SP with temp tables with indexes based on each Views SQL to have it all in one place for the SSRS?

If the answer is that 'it depends on what I want', I would be grateful if you point me to any resources that can give me an idea of ideal setup to get query data to SSRS with minimal performance issues.

Thanking you kindly

---

Background/Explanation
SQL Server is not foreign to me but I don’t consider myself experienced (1 year) enough in developing 'etiquette' when it comes to crafting the parts of SQL Server. I feel I'm developing a lot of **bad habits** formed from using basic SQL knowledge, online searches and the odd MS SQL server course. The amount of searching done has been endless and I’m not saying there isn’t an answer out there for each part of SQL Server (UDFs, SPs and Views) out there.

The company I work for has many servers, many databases, for many outsourced front end systems being used. The issue is performance and the more I search the more I realize the setup of our databases could now maybe completely **negligent and amateur**. When I joined the setup used a lot of views each 'end' view had a dependency tree of over 4+ views including use of functions, each view ranging from aggregate calculations for Statistics to rearranging via pivots and unpivots. The reason given to me was so that we can pick out the parts that have gone wrong in which view. To no surprise the server has now suddenly had enough of this and peaks at 100% every time a report or view ran affecting the front end systems performance for the users.

My PP stresses my frustration and my position with the company (code monkey) in finding an answer myself which has resulted in pushing the keys back in the keyboard with opposable thumbs and appeal to the experts here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is really too broad for stackoverflow. I'll try to give you a quick overview of what I think you're asking but really you're asking for way too much for a single answer here. This site is mainly focused around solving a specific problem and not the general process of development. I expect someone will probably come along and close your question.

### Nightly table loads

Depending on the complexity of the task this is exactly what SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) is for. You can build automated processes that do data transformations and data loads. It is used to build maintainable data integration solutions. Learning to use SSIS (especially properly) is a whole task though. In fact the 3rd exam for the SQL Server 2012 MCSA is exclusively about SSIS. Though if your table loads are not that complicated running them as SQL Tasks could be just as effective.

### Database structure and use of views/SPs/functions/etc

This is an incredibly deep subject and it is totally dependent on what you're trying to do, how your data is structured, what kind of hardware you've got running, etc. Certainly using views, functions, and stored procedures can be good. They enable code re-use and allow you to encapsulate the logic for SSRS reports away from the actual report writers.

However, the SQL needs to be well written or it will suffer from performance problems. But, of course, that is just how it is no matter where you put the code. Even if the SQL is just a dataset in an SSRS report it will run slowly and hammer the server if it isn't written well. If the database isn't configured correctly it can have terrible performance. Indexes and other techniques for speeding up databases will always be important.

Above all everything needs to be documented so that someone else (or your later self) can make sense of it in ten months when something breaks.

### Training

I would highly recommend trying to convince your employer to send you on some courses to learn SQL Server if they expect you to be developing complex database solutions. Certainly taking the courses to get your MCSA in SQL Server 2012 would be very useful. Getting the certification certainly opened my eyes to many possibilities for achieving things that I didn't know about before or just hadn't thought of.

The first exam will cover writing SQL queries and the different things that can help performance and the many cool features that you can leverage when retrieving or writing data. The second exam will cover database server administration, troubleshooting, and some performance tuning. The third exam is all about SSIS and how to warehouse your data to enable better analysis and reporting.

Even if you just read the Microsoft Learning books for these exams and never take the tests you will gain a lot of knowledge. There are other books that are good too such as [T-SQL Fundamentals by Itzik Ben-Gan](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735658145) but ultimately it sounds like you need to get a lot deeper knowledge of the SQL Server platform before you can really make good design decisions about how to implement your solutions.

### Conclusion

In the end, programming is programming. Trying to make a maintainable solution that works is your first goal. Tuning the performance of the system comes after that. The specifics of the languages and platforms don't take away from any of that. But in order to get the best performance out of a system you need knowledge about that system. An answer on here isn't going to be able to give you everything you need to know.